# Get error when using $filter and $expand in postman

Tags: odata, sap-business-bydesign

I am having two entitities in SAP BYD :

> Account  * Account_id
>
> - Value
> - Company
>
> Company  * Company_id
>
> - Date

Account has a `1:n` association to Company
this is a example url i used:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxxxx/Account?$expand=Bar &$filter=Date gt datetime'2023-12-31T23:59:59'
```

but I got error:

> **"Left hand expression of memberaccess operator has wrong cardinality (to many not allowed)"**

I don't know why and what is the solution for this error, please help me.

[image: Array SS here]

I try to query odata in sap byd using `$expand` and `$filter` but I got this error:

> "Left hand expression of memberaccess operator has wrong cardinality (to many not allowed)"

I hope to find a reason why this happen and solution to fix it